# how get multiple value Regex expressions in Java

Tags: java, regex

how to get all word if it has _I, im using "\S*_I+\S*".

I Have String :
the_B-NP camera_I-NP is_B-VP very_B-ADJP easy_I-ADJP to_B-VP use_I-VP ,_O in_B-PP fact_B-NP on_B-PP a_B-NP recent_I-NP trip_I-NP this_B-NP past_I-NP week_I-NP i_I-NP was_B-VP asked_I-VP to_B-VP take_I-VP a_B-NP picture_I-NP of_B-PP a_B-NP vacationing_I-NP elderly_I-NP group_I-NP ._O

this my code

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\S*_I+\\S*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    while(m.find()){
        hasilReg = m.group();
    }
```

after compile i got only one value : group_I-NP
but i would like all word if it has _I

thanks

Comment: [It seems to work](http://ideone.com/wyR6D3). The problem is that perhaps, you reassign the `hasilReg` value all the time. Add the results to a `List<String>`

Comment: List<String> hasilReg = new ArrayList<String>(); like this? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: done, thx @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: I posted an answer, please accept if it is working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `group_I-NP`  is the last value and you only get this because you reassign the `hasilReg` value all the time. Add the results to a `List<String>`:

```
String str = "the_B-NP camera_I-NP is_B-VP very_B-ADJP easy_I-ADJP to_B-VP use_I-VP ,_O in_B-PP fact_B-NP on_B-PP a_B-NP recent_I-NP trip_I-NP this_B-NP past_I-NP week_I-NP i_I-NP was_B-VP asked_I-VP to_B-VP take_I-VP a_B-NP picture_I-NP of_B-PP a_B-NP vacationing_I-NP elderly_I-NP group_I-NP ._O ";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("\\S*_I+\\S*");
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(str);
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    lst.add(matcher.group());
}
System.out.println(lst);
// => [camera_I-NP, easy_I-ADJP, use_I-VP, recent_I-NP, trip_I-NP, past_I-NP, week_I-NP, i_I-NP, asked_I-VP, take_I-VP, picture_I-NP, vacationing_I-NP, elderly_I-NP, group_I-NP]
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/wyR6D3)

Comment: Could you please help me on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43144867/getting-last-match-from-multiple-matches)?